# "Access is denied" GCC C compile

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I know there have been similar questions but none of them seem to solve my problem. After successfully compiling my code, I got an "Access is denied." message from my command prompt after trying to run it (picture below).

[image: Command Prompt Message]

The code I'm trying to run in a file named **dummyC.c** is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("Hello");
}
```

For context, I'm using Windows 10 64-bit. The GCC version (`GCC -v`) is MinGW 9.2.0, also in the attached picture. Is there any way I could solve this?

**EDIT: The problem was my Avast antivirus flagging the output file `a.exe` as a Trojan or a virus. The problem was solved after I temporarily disabled all Avast shields.**

Comment: Looks like a security feature that keeps you from running executables in that folder.

Comment: If you have all the MinGW tools in your path, try `chmod +x a.exe` - I think that can matter for Cygwin, and MinGW is based on Cygwin.

Comment: Try opening the console as an administrator.

Comment: What is "a"? You don't seem to be creating a binary. Try `gcc dummyC.c -otest.exe` and then execute `test.exe`.

Comment: @Lundin I think a (or a.exe) is the the equivalent of the Unix/Linux a.out

Comment: @Jabberwocky Maybe but I'm not sure there's an exe extension, in which case Windows can decide to run something else called `a` in your PATH. Regardless, there's no reason not to name the executable something meaningful.

Comment: After compiling, it spits out an "a.exe" file. Running as admin doesn't work but I just noticed my Avast keeps flagging and quarantining the a.exe file. I'll try disabling it

Comment: @frostrivera19 is seems you've found the problem.

Comment: @frostrivera19: If that worked, please post an answer.

Comment: IT WORKED! The antivirus was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your project is not in the correct place for the compiler to execute it, if it is on the desktop try to transfer it to a folder created in c:

Comment: pode ser que você não esteja acessando o software como root